# ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "books" has no column named "loves"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, fixtures

Bizarre Rails problem.

I have a `Book` entity and users can `Love` a book.

All my other models are fine and passing all the tests but after generating the new `Love` model and setting the fixtures, I am getting a ton of these errors out of the blue:

```
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "books" has no column named "loves".
```

I somehow think it's to do with reserved keywords in Rails perhaps?

Is `Love` a reserved keyword by any chance?

I did a search on this page:

https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/

And the word `love` yields no results.

### Love Migration File

```
class CreateLoves < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :loves do |t|
      t.references :book, foreign_key: true
      t.references :sender, foreign_key: true
      t.references :receiver, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

### Love Model

```
class Love < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"
end
```

### Love Fixtures

```
one:
  book: one
  sender: jim
  receiver: sarah

two:
  book: two
  sender: sarah
  receiver: jim

three:
  book: three
  sender: jim
  receiver: tycus
```

### Book Model

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: "User"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
  has_many :loves
end
```

### Book Fixtures

```
one:
  title: Back To The Future
  adult_content: true
  author: jim
  published: false
  genres: action, comedy, science_fiction

two:
  title: Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone
  adult_content: false
  author: sarah
  published: false
  genres: action, fantasy

three:
  title: Back To The Future 2
  adult_content: true
  author: jim
  published: false
  genres: action, comedy, science_fiction

four:
  title: Back To The Future 3
  adult_content: true
  author: jim
  published: false
  genres: action, comedy, science_fiction

five:
  title: Royal Guard
  adult_content: true
  author: chewedon
  published: false
  genres: action, romance, fantasy
```

### Books Controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:index, :create]
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index

  def index
    books = policy_scope(Book.all)
    render json: books
  end

  def create
    book = Book.new(book_params)

    if book.save
      render json: book, status: :created
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def show
    book = Book.find_by(id: params[:id])

    if book.present?
      authorize book
      render json: book
    else
      skip_authorization
      render status: :not_found
    end
  end

  def update
    book = Book.find_by(id: params[:id])

    skip_authorization and render status: :not_found and return unless book

    authorize book

    if book.update!(book_params)
      render json: book
    else
      render status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    book = Book.find_by(id: params[:id])

    skip_authorization and render status: :not_found and return unless book

    authorize book

    if book.destroy!
      render status: :ok
    end
  end


  private

  def book_params
    params.permit(:title, :adult_content, :published, :author_id, genre_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Here are some of my other model and their test fixtures, they all pass the tests:

### Chapter Fixtures

```
one:
  title: Straw House
  order: 1
  content: First pig built a house out of straw
  published: true
  book: one

two:
  title: Wooden House
  order: 2
  content: Second pig built a house out of wood
  published: true
  book: one

three:
  title: Brick House
  order: 3
  content: Third pig built a house out of brick
  published: false
  book: one

four:
  title: Hogwarts School of Wizardry
  order: 1
  content: They pushed their troller into nine and three quarters
  published: false
  book: two
```

### Comment Fixtures

```
one:
  content: Love this chapter
  author: jim
  book: one
  chapter: one

two:
  content: Hate this chapter
  author: sarah
  book: two
  chapter: two

three:
  content: Interesting chapter
  author: tycus
  book: one
  chapter: one
```

### Message Fixtures

```
one:
  subject: Next Chapter
  body: When will the next chapter be published?
  sender_read: false
  receiver_read: false
  sender: jim
  receiver: sarah

two:
  subject: Film Adaptation
  body: I would like to turn your story into a film
  sender_read: false
  receiver_read: false
  sender: sarah
  receiver: jim

three:
  subject: Mind Blown
  body: Where do you get all these ideas? I'll stalk you now!
  sender_read: false
  receiver_read: false
  sender: tycus
  receiver: jim
```

What could be the problem?

### Update

If I comment out my Love Fixtures:

```
# one:
#   book: one
#   sender: jim
#   receiver: sarah
#
# two:
#   book: two
#   sender: sarah
#   receiver: jim
#
# three:
#   book: three
#   sender: jim
#   receiver: tycus
```

I get new test errors:

```
Error:
BooksControllerTest#test_book_show_-_should_show_book_info:
NameError: uninitialized constant Book::Lofe
    app/controllers/books_controller.rb:26:in `show'
    test/controllers/books_controller_test.rb:63:in `block in <class:BooksControllerTest>'
```

Where the heck did **`Lofe`** come from?

I quadruple checked my spelling of Love. I even did an entire project search for word "Lofe" and it doesn't show any search results matching.

Comment: What is in app/controllers/books_controller.rb:26 ?

Comment: I've updated my question to include Book Controller. Line 26 is: `render json: book` but I don't think it's my Books Controller. Prior to generating the new model, all my tests were passing. These new errors that show are showing for all my Book test.

Comment: try `has_many :loves, class_name: 'Love'`

Comment: adding `has_many :loves, class_name: "Love"` and keeping my Love fixtures commented out makes all my tests pass but when I re-enable my Love fixtures, the `ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "loves" has no column named "book".` error is showing up again. More to the point though, I shouldn't need to be explicit about the class name since the model is called Love, not Mud :D

Comment: @Zhang because it has no such column. Change in fixtures to `book_id`

Comment: Changing to book_id in my Love fixture made no difference. I don't believe I need to type `book_id` in fixtures. I have other models like `Message, Chapter, Genre, Comment` and in their fixture files, I don't use the foreign key column name, I use the property name. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Zhang Ok, I never used fixtures, so it was a suggestion. Sadly not correct one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Wild guess***, but I think, it's because of how [`Inflector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) treats your `has_many :loves` line.

I think it assumes, that singular from `loves` is `lofe`, thus the error, because it tries to resolve the constant `Lofe` in the scope of `Book` class.

To override the default behaviour, see the very first block of code from the docs:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'octopus', 'octopi'
  # for your case it's
  inflect.irregular 'love', 'loves'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

@andreyDeineko is right, if you do `"loves".singularize` you get `lofe`

You can override how rails determines singular / plural in your environment or application rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'love', 'loves'
end
```

Comment: Wow...lol, I don't know who to give the answer to.My english isn't great, but I have never heard of the word Lofe before. Adding this to the `config/initializer/inflectors.rb` fixes the problem.

Comment: I'll give it to Andrey, since he answered first but I hope others can upvote Steve's answer to compensate. I can't double upvote unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks. @AndreyDeineko all's well that ends well!