# Rails: underscore in table name confuses fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails application with 3 models, `OrderItem`, `Photo` and `PhotoSize`

From schema.rb, this is my table `order_item` (I removed here irrelevant columns):

```
  create_table "order_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "order_id"
    t.integer "photo_size_id"
    t.integer "photo_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_order_items_on_order_id"
    t.index ["photo_id"], name: "index_order_items_on_photo_id"
    t.index ["photo_size_id"], name: "index_order_items_on_photo_size_id"
  end
```

The generate fixture file looks like:

```
one:
  order: one
  photo_size: one
  photo: one

two:
  order: two
  photo_size: two
  photo: two
```

Now running my tests I'm getting the error

> ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "order_items" has no column
>   named "photo_size".

Now having `photo` in the fixture with the corresponding `photo_id` in the table works fine. `photo_size` with its corresponding `photo_size_id` throws an error though. Can any one explain this discrepancy, and how can this problem be fixed?

I tried the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846420/activerecordfixturefixtureerror-table-books-has-no-column-named-loves) of adding a statement for how to pluralize photo_size, but this didn't fix the problem. Commenting out the fixture file stops the error naturally as expected though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a `belongs_to :photo_size` in your `OrderItem` model?

Comment: No I have there a has_one :photo_size

Comment: Should be a `belongs_to` - that's your problem.  The `belongs_to` belongs on whichever model the foreign key column is on.

Comment: Yep, sometimes it doesn't make sense (and sometimes the fact that it doesn't make sense is a hint that you've put the fkey in the wrong table :)

Answer (score 1):

The label references for associations only work on the `belongs_to` association because it depends on the foreign key, which is on the class that is declaring the `belongs_to` association.

[From https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Label+references+for+associations+-28belongs_to-2C+has_one-2C+has_many-29)

> Specifying foreign keys in fixtures can be very fragile, not to mention difficult to read. Since Active Record can figure out the ID of any fixture from its label, you can specify FK's by label instead of ID.

[From API dock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods):

> The `#belongs_to` association is always used in the model that has the foreign key.